# Browser specific css for Internet Explorer

Tags: css

Is there any way to Implement Browser specific css other than IE conditional comments..?
I already tried with IE conditional comments,i wrote two css file one is specific for IE(css_IE.css) other one is for all the browsers(css_gen.css),have observed some the properties in css_IE.css are overridden by properties in css_gen.css file.

Comment: A CSS for IE doesn't make sense today. Recent versions of IE are very similar to standard browsers. If you really need to target some browser (which I doubt), the version is important.

Comment: You need to make sure that the IE specific CSS file is loaded *after* the generic one. Also, any selectors in the IE specific CSS need to be of the same or higher specificity as the generic one.

Comment: @dystroy,i tried in IE8 and below versions

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Load the css_gen.css file first and then load the css_IE.css file.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/css_gen.css">
<!--[if IE 6]>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/css_IE.css">
<![endif]-->
```

Hope that solves your problem.

And try this too http://css-tricks.com/how-to-create-an-ie-only-stylesheet/